# Close Workbook After "Workbook_Open()" is Run

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a program that runs as soon as the workbook is open using the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` function located in the `ThisWorkbook` object. I would like to add a closing function as well, so that basically the program will run as soon as the workbook is open, and then close right away so it never stays open, just runs and closes.

I've tried adding:

```
Workbooks("Fire Ext. Comments EXE.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

...right before the `End Sub` at the bottom of the program, but the workbook stays open so I'm wondering if it belongs in a different module and then called separately? Let me know what you think.

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: Did not work. Workbook stays open. I tried placing it above the End Sub

Comment: Is your `Workbook_Open` definitely running?

Comment: I stand corrected. My computer needed an update/restart. Tried your solution again and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, so that the application itself will close

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit
```

Comment: Hey, didn't work unfortunately. Workbook stayed open